# incoming call and message broadcast reciever not working in 6.0+ when app remove from recent task

Tags: android

incoming call and message broadcast reciever not working in 6.0+ when app remove from recent task.But worrking properly in lollipop 5.01

anyone with permissions 
which permission to use

mine buildsdktool is 23

Here is my reciever :

```
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.MsgReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "kuj to oo gaw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Paste your code here.

Comment: Here is my reciever
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
  Toast.makeText(context,"toast",Length).show();
  }
  <receiver android:name=".receiver.MsgReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
register from service class
  msgrcvr=new MsgReceiver();
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
        registerReceiver(msgrcvr,intentFilter);
working fine but when app remove from recent task nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the receivers with the corresponding intents in the manifest.xml?

e.g.

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

with the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Also keep in mind, that you have to check the permissions in Android 6+ during the runtime and ask the user to grant it, if you don't have them.

Comment: at runtime what permission i should ask to user 
i ask them for sms permission at runtime but what for broadcast reciever

Comment: for calls you need the permission READ_PHONE_STATE. Maybe check the app settings on the androd 6 phone if the Permissions ar granted.

Comment: but my ques is why broadcast reciever is not working on marshmellow as i remove app from recent is there any other permission require or some other way to make that reciever work ?
looking for solution from last three days 
any link or example also be appreciated

Comment: you understand the new permission system in android 6? in android 5 the user have to grant all permisions at app install.. since android 6 he can grant/revoke permissions at any time. so you have to be sure the the user have given your app at least READ_PHONE_STATE and RECEIVE_SMS.
further Informations to Android 6 Permissions at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html